# Extenção AJAX Cart with Drag & Drop Magento não funciona em home page

Tags: magento

eu sou novo com o magento, já procurei bastante coisas sobre essa extenção, mas não encontro nada. Ela está funcionando normalmente nos produtos, mas na lista de produtos na home page não funciona, alguém por favor poderia me indicar uma possével causa?
Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Ziru, Você tentou ver se não é algum outro módulo, que está gerando incompatibilidade? Testou isso em uma instalação limpa? Abs

Comment: Testei, na instalação limpa não funcionou nem ao menos onde estava funcionando.